# Mobile website, portrait to landscape

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I'm making a mobile website, in portrait the nav bar is sized nicely with 15px of padding around the top and bottom, but when I switch to landscape mode, it takes up almost half the screen.

What is the best way to go about this so it's smaller?

A separate stylesheet or is there a trick I don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use this for my client mobile site and its work correcly :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="[css_file]">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="[css_file]">
```

the css file can be same

Comment: But what happens when they flip the phone after the page has loaded? The new css wont be read in?

Comment: the CSS file will be re-read.. so the design will be fixed... :D

Answer (score 1):

[Responsive Design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)

I think this will be usefull :D